# How To Load An Enum Of The Name Given In Method Argument?

Tags: java, methods, enums, arguments

I'm trying to call the value of an Enum from the method arguments.

Tried the code, sorry if there's a lot of useless or spurious stuff in it. Obviously this doesn't execute! It's just the bits that I think are relevant

```
public int choosemachines(int cost){    

  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Which One Would You Like?");

  int choice = scanner.nextInt(); 
  switch (choice) {         
      case 1:
        writeArrays("MACHINE1", 1);
        break;
}

public void writeArrays(String **machine**, int arrint) {   

        if (cost >= machines.**machine**.getcost()) {

            int alsize = twoDim.size();
            twoDim.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
            twoDim.get(alsize).add(arrint);
            twoDim.get(alsize).add(1);
            twoDim.get(alsize).add(1);
            System.out.println(alsize);

             for (ArrayList<Integer> row : twoDim)
             {
                for (Integer element : row)
                {
                   System.out.print(element + "        ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
            else {
            System.out.println("Can't Afford It...");

            }   
        }

public enum machines {

    MACHINE1("General Electric Caffeinator", 1500, "TWO"),
    MACHINE2("Sleepless Night", 2000, "ONE")
    ;

    private String name;
    private int cost;
    private String coffeeType;

    machines (String n, int c, String cT) {
        name = n;
        cost = c;
        coffeeType = cT;
    }

    String getname(){
        return name;
    }

    int getcost(){
        return cost;
    }

    String getcoffeeType() {
        return coffeeType;
    }
}
```

I expect the if function to get the cost listed in the second place of the Enum. Could also work for me with an integer instead of MACHINE1 but this doesn't seem to be a valid name within the Enum.

Comment: " sorry if there's a lot of useless or spurious stuff in it." please clean the code before posting. See [mcve].

Comment: Ok, read that and will make sure I do so in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming the Enum to `Machine` as per java naming conventions, you could do it like so:

```
public void writeArrays(String machineName, int arrint) {

    int cost = 0;
    for(Machine machine : Machine.values()){
        if(machine.getname().equals(machineName)){
            cost = machine.getcost();
            break;
        }
    }
    //todo add rest of the code 
}
```

You could also add a utility method to `Machines`

```
 public static Machine getByName(String machineName) {

    for(Machine machine : Machine.values()){
        if(machine.getname().equals(machineName))
            return machine;
    }
    return null;
}
```

test it using: `System.out.println(Machine.getByName("Sleepless Night").getcost());`